# How to find roots of $x^2 - 1$ in $\mathbb{C}$ by ideal thoery

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

I want to find roots of $x^2 - 1$ in $\mathbb{C}$ by ideal theory.
I have thought the following:
At first, we examine prime ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2 - 1)$ except $(0)$.
So they are $(x+1)/(x^2 -1)$ and $(x-1)/(x^2 -1)$.
$\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a PID, whence $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2 - 1)$ is a PID and hence prime ideals other than $(0)$ is maximal ideal.
By hilbert nullstellensatz maximal ideals corresponds to roots as a maximal ideal $(x-a)$ $\longleftrightarrow$ point a $a$.
Therefore roots of $x^2 - 1$ are $1$ and $-1$.

Is it correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get it. Finding roots by ideal theory?? You need the roots of $x^2-1$ to find the prime ideals of $\Bbb{C}[x]/(x^2-1)$, don't you? Why run in circles like that?

Comment: “Whence $\mathbb C[x]/(x^2-1)$ is a PID.”  Uh, $R[x]/(x^2-1)$ is never a domain for any ring $R$, so it is not a PID.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We can't find it in the ideal theory.